Character doesn`t spawn on imported arena
I have imported a multiplayer arena, but my character cant spawn on it from player start. It feels like space in arena is also a part of the mesh. But when i am put player start out of the arena it spawns correctly. i havent found an answer in google, so i am asking it here
